# How to make GEdit a good jQuery/Web Design editor?

Tags: jquery, plugins, gedit

I want to have Syntax Highlighting for jQuery and maybe when I type `<html>` it can automatically insert `</html>`. Is there anyway to make GEdit do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the difference between jQuery syntax and JS syntax ? :)
For auto complete functionality you'll need to import jQuery snippets, just follow <s>[this guide](http://www.danielcamargo.com.br/stuffs/gedit-snippets-jquery/)</s> (dead link)

For more intelligent JS coding in gedit I'll advice to use JSLint, look how to [integrate it into gedit](https://web.archive.org/web/20090507064250/http://www.j4mie.org/2009/01/14/javascript-syntax-checking-from-gedit) . You'll need to activate External Tools plugin.

Good luck to you with gedit and JS :) Really nice technologies.

Comment: My main beef with GEdit is that it doesn't highlight `document`, or `window`.

Comment: I'm running it in Ubuntu with Gnome so I don't know if it is a universal method. Gedit is using gtksourceview for syntax highlighting. All you need is edit file /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/javascript.lang (you'll need root permissions) and add 
     
<keyword>window</keyword>
<keyword>document</keyword>
    
there as object type nodes (if you like to highlight it as objects). Yes, and feel free to contact me if there are any issues at mushex@antarnian .

Comment: Thanks your last comment was extremely helpful. Now they `document` and `window` actually look like something special, instead of just another thing.

Comment: To add html tag completion, checkout zen coding plugin http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/ for gedit.